# RoR, mongoid: BSON cannot serialize object on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, bson

I have the model anwer_pair.rb

```
class AnswerPair
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :question
  embedded_in :survey
  field :answer1, type: String
  field :answer2, type: String
  ...
  field :correct, type: Boolean, default: true
  ...
  def self.buildnew(answer1 = "answer1", answer2 = "answer2", correct = false)
    ap = AnswerPair.new
    ap.answer1 = answer1
    ap.answer2 = answer2
    ap.correct = correct
    return ap
  end
  ...
end
```

which is nested in question.rb

```
class Question
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...
  field :name, type: String
  ...
  embeds_many :answer_pairs
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answer_pairs, allow_destroy: true
  before_save :fill_up_answer_pairs
  ...
  def delete_all_false_answer_pairs
    if(self.answer_pairs.any?)
      self.answer_pairs.where(correct: false).each do |pair|
        pair.delete
      end
    end
  end

  def fill_up_answer_pairs
    if(self.answer_pairs.any?)
      self.answer_pairs.where(correct: true).each do |pair1|
        self.answer_pairs.where(correct: true).each do |pair2|
          if(pair1.answer1 != pair2.answer1)
            if(pair1.answer2 != pair2.answer2) 
              self.add_to_set(:answer_pairs, AnswerPair.buildnew(pair1.answer1, pair2.answer2, false)) 
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Using a form to create a question works fine (I use mongoid). The User can't select whether an answer pair is correct or not. It's correct by default, like you see above. The wrong answer pairs are added automatically by the "before_save :fill_up_answer_pairs". Now comes the problem. In order to edit a question, I delete all wrong answer pairs like this

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
     ...
     def edit
       @question.delete_all_false_answer_pairs
     end
end
```

and use again a form. So far, so good, but when I submit the form and it comes to the "before_save :fill_up_answer_pairs", I get an error

```
BSON::InvalidDocument at /questions/548dc31288a49401b50000c2
Cannot serialize an object of class AnswerPair into BSON.
```

at the line "self.add_to_set...". Could anybody tell me, why it works with the create method but not with the edit method? What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

add

```
after_save :fill_up_answer_pairs
```

to your Question model and change

```
self.add_to_set(:answer_pairs, AnswerPair.buildnew(pair1.answer1, pair2.answer2, false))
```

to

```
self.answer_pairs.create(:answer1 => pair1.answer1, :answer2 => pair2.answer2, :correct => false)
```

Then it should work